My Blog refused to connect to my phone. What could be the problem and possible solution
Recently, I bought a new phone itel P55T. I tried viewing my blog https://www.christianresoursescentre.org.ng/
but it wouldn't connect even when other sites are connecting in my phone.
When I use my wife's phone Oppo A16 and PC my blog connects.
I restarted my phone but it wouldn't connect

I updated my chrome browser and tried connecting my blog and it connected.
Thanks
